# Error setting OLEDB connection

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

> ERROR: One or more missing parameters.

```
Using MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection = FrmCommonCodes.GetConnection(),
    MyCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT protectioncode FROM settings", MyConnection)
    If MyConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConnection.Open()
    Using MyDataReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader
        While MyDataReader.Read
            GetProtectionCodeCheck = MyDataReader("protectioncode")
        End While
    End Using
End Using
MsgBox(GetProtectionCodeCheck)
```

Comment: The code you posted wouldn't have compiled as it was.  I had to add the `End If` line.  If you got that wrong, I have to wonder what else you got wrong and how closely what you posted resembles your actual code.

Comment: Also, I have to wonder why you're calling `ExecuteReader`. If you only want one value then you should be calling `ExecuteScalar`. If you do want multiple values then why are you only using one variable to store them?

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I removed the End If because the If Then is a one-liner. I do wonder if the comma belongs on the first line.

Comment: Oh bugger! I didn't notice that. My apologies.

Comment: @jmcilhinney 
1. I tried `ExecuteScalar` with one field name.  Then its showing "oledbexception was handled.","No value given for one or more required parameters"
2. Also tried with `ExecuteReader`, and the sql was `Select * FROM settings`.  Then the error is "IndexOutOfRangeException was handled" protectioncode

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` has nothing to do with your issue. It's just the logical option when what you want is to retrieve one value. You're still executing the same query so it won't fix any issues with the query. The reason for your issue is not clear. Two things I would try, more in hope than knowledge, is to escape your identifiers, i.e. use "SELECT [protectioncode] FROM [settings]" or whatever is appropriate for your database, and also to try that query in something other than your app, e.g. if it's an Access database then try the query in Access.

Comment: "No value given for one or more required parameters." is thrown if the column name is wrong. Double check that protectioncode is the correct column name.

Answer (score 1):

The column name `protectioncode` is wrong.

`"SELECT protectioncode FROM settings"` will give you the exception "No value given for one or more required parameters." if `protectioncode` is not a valid column name in that table.

If you change the query to `SELECT * from settings` it will instead fail on the `MyDataReader("protectioncode")` because "protectioncode" is not one of the column names.